# How to deploy capistrano sidekiq monit with correct permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, capistrano3, monit, sidekiq-monitor

The problem is when I use monit with capistrano. What is my mistakes?

```
INFO [843c196b] Running /usr/bin/env sudo mv /tmp/monit.conf /etc/monit/conf.d/sidekiq_admin-api_production.conf as deployer@XXXXXXXXXX
DEBUG [843c196b] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 /usr/bin/env sudo mv /tmp/monit.conf /etc/monit/conf.d/sidekiq_admin-api_production.conf )
DEBUG [843c196b]    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@XXXXXXXXXX: sudo exit status: 1
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I tried ssh key authorization.

Change permission of folders for my user (/tmp/monit.conf /etc/monit/conf.d/)

set :pty, false

set :use_sudo, false

sudo file

My sudo file is:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a sudo directive which allows the command to run without entering the password. The error is telling you that sudo is trying to ask for a password and cannot. Probably the NOPASSWD command.

Comment: Well I change  to %sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL, It worker =D

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In capistrano 3 you need to set pty.  Allowing the sudo command on your server without entering a password can risk your server.

```
set :pty, true
```